# Have to join tables but only want to delete from first table

Tags: java, sqlite

So I have table1 and table2. Table1 has columns configId, timestamp, value. Table2 has configId, machineId, ioid, iotype, lock. The relationship is many Table1 items to 1 Table2 item. Table one is the data, Table2 is the identifiers.

I want to delete items in table 1, but have to make sure that lock = 0 in table2 where table1.configId = table2.configId. Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mySQL you can do something like

```
DELETE FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.configId = t1.configId
WHERE t2.lock = 0;
```

If not, you can try something like

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE configId IN (
SELECT t1.configId FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.configId = t1.configId
WHERE t2.lock = 0
)
```

Comment: Yeah I only noticed the tag on the question after my post :P